# Centering an ImageButton and a TextView in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

`android:layout_gravity="center"` doesn't seem to work the same in a `RelativeLayout` as it does in a `LinearLayout`.

I would like both an `ImageButton` and a `TextView` to be centered in a `RelativeLayout` - is there a basic `xml` code for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

Also :

```
android:layout_centerInParent 
android:layout_centerVertical
```

Comment: 8 years is a long time, so this is an update to the answer. `RelativeLayout` parent's `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` should be `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`. All the other attributes below the first (top most) attribute property is the same, and they belong in the children of `RelativeLayout`. Then again, `RelativeLayout` should be `ConstraintLayout` instead.